# Accidentally looped mail() in PHP! Been getting emails since last night. How do I stop it?

Tags: php

Yup, I did the stupidest of stupid acts. I looped mail() accidentally and now, since 8:30 last night, I have gotten nearly 2000 emails from my server.

He claims to have rebooted it, but I still get the emails.. I can tell they were sent a while ago because the email's content is about 24 hours outdated.

How do I stop this!

Comment: switching off your server may prevent even more being sent, but for the mails that have already been sent you're just going to have to wait it out while they work their way through the internet. This may take quite a while if the volumes are high. You may just have to set your spam filter to discard them.

Comment: Create a new mailbox, its free!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete all email from queue like this:

```
ls /var/spool/mqueue | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the php file from you server and wait. The e-mails maybe delayed because of the amount.